# Know Whether Guest User or Registered User buy any thing on current session

Tags: magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I am new in magento.How can we check whether Guest User or Registered user buy any thing on current session of browser using programatically ? I want to make one analysis form based on that check . So please help me out. Any suggestion will guide me to my journey.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the quote object for that. It has a method that returns the number of items in the quote (or cart).

```
echo Mage::getModel('checkout/cart')->getQuote()->getItemsCount(); // number of items in cart
```

Comment: What happen if user add to cart product but did not check out ?

Comment: As long as the cart is in the session it will display the right count. When the session no longer exists the count to will be 0